# Crittercism does not handle the crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In Crittercism App Loads Today I see number of App Loads. But when I make crash I don't see anything in **Crashes Today** . 
I do crash .

```
if (tabBar.tag == 1 && item.tag == 2) {;
 [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException  format:@"Foo must not be nil"];
};
```

Or crash .

`if (tabBar.tag == 1 && item.tag == 2) {;
     [NSException raise:@"error!" format:@"it go!"];
  };`

Or crash .

```
if (tabBar.tag == 1 && item.tag == 2) {;
 [self wrongselector];
```

};

What should I do to make it handle crash?

Comment: Are you in debug mode or run mode? If you are debugging your app, the debugger will capture the error, and Crittercism has no chance to handle it.
And Crittercism's crash report is down sometimes, maybe later it will be OK.

Comment: I'm in ebug mode . Actually information appears in Exceptions Today but after 3 hours since crashes.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. How did you fixed? Im trying with my own App and with the Demo App but none of them reports the crashes, just the App loads and the exceptions.

Comment: Did anyone find why this was happening? @ij_